# Using LEFT OUTER JOIN return one matched row and additional only matching id's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a large database that has about 190 columns in 22 tables. There are a few tables that allow multiple entries into the database all of the values are referenced by a foreign key. When I use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` If there are multiple entries in a single column matching a specific ID then it creates a new row with all of the information as before only changing the table fields. For example:

```
+-----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-------+-------+---------+-------------------------------+
| CompanyID | Name                      | Address                     | City           | State | Zip   | Country | Website                       |
+-----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-------+-------+---------+-------------------------------+
|       227 | Hello Company             | 123 blvd                    | Boom           | OK    | 56008 | USA     | www.imtired.com               |
|       228 | Test Company              | 87 Wesley Street            | Denham         | LA    | 21726 | USA     | www.tests.com                 |
|       229 | Testing Company           | 2 US hwy 281 N.             | Antonio        | TX    | 64258 | USA     | www.modeling.com              |
|       230 | TestCompany               | 45 W. 95th St               | Oak Lawn       | IL    | 61453 | USA     | www.express.com               |
|       235 | Encore                    | 2142 S. Patterson           | City           | IA    | 43106 | USA     | www.boomsite.com              |
|       235 | Encore                    | 2142 S. Patterson           | City           | IA    | 43106 | USA     | www.testingsite.com           |
+-----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-------+-------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

You see that the company Encore has two rows with only the website being different is there a way to make it like this:

```
+-----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-------+-------+---------+-------------------------------+
| CompanyID | Name                      | Address                     | City           | State | Zip   | Country | Website                       |
+-----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-------+-------+---------+-------------------------------+
|       227 | Hello Company             | 123 blvd                    | Boom           | OK    | 56008 | USA     | www.imtired.com               |
|       228 | Test Company              | 87 Wesley Street            | Denham         | LA    | 21726 | USA     | www.tests.com                 |
|       229 | Testing Company           | 2 US hwy 281 N.             | Antonio        | TX    | 64258 | USA     | www.modeling.com              |
|       230 | TestCompany               | 45 W. 95th St               | Oak Lawn       | IL    | 61453 | USA     | www.express.com               |
|       235 | Encore                    | 2142 S. Patterson           | City           | IA    | 43106 | USA     | www.boomsite.com              |
|           |                           |                             |                |       |       |         | www.testingsite.com           |
+-----------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-------+-------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

This is a snippet of the query I am using :

```
SELECT * FROM `company` C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN owner O USING ( CompanyID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales S USING ( CompanyID )
```

Comment: This type of data modification is probably best done at the application layer.  Just keep track of the company, and on second and subsequent occurrences blank out the columns you want blanked out.

Comment: Did my answer below solve your issue?

Comment: Yes thank you but I commented with a preference I keep getting a syntax error if I remove the comma and try using a `\r`

Comment: Did you try "\r\n". Make sure to use double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this in mySQL. It will give comma separated websites whenever there are multiple rows with everything same except the website

```
SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(website,',') as website FROM `company` C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN owner O USING ( CompanyID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales S USING ( CompanyID )
GROUP BY CompanyID
```

Comment: This works great but I would prefer a new line so I am using \r but I keep getting a comma, I would prefer to just have a new line and no comma I am using ``SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(TradeShowName,'\r') as TradeShowName FROM `tradeshownamesattended` C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN owner O USING ( CompanyID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales S USING ( CompanyID )
GROUP BY CompanyID`` but I get a syntax error if I remove the comma

Comment: Can you help me with the proper syntax to do more than one group I have approximately six tables that have multiple entries that need to be grouped like website I have been trying to implement the code in the same way but I can't figure it out maybe an example of website from the company table and tradeshowname from tradeshownamesattended

Comment: I got this working except now every row has the duplicate information for tradeshows ``SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( website,  ',' ) AS website
FROM  `company` C
LEFT OUTER JOIN owner O
USING ( CompanyID ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales S
USING ( CompanyID ) , (
SELECT TradeShowName, GROUP_CONCAT( TradeShowName,  ',' ) AS tradeshownames
FROM  `tradeshownamesattended` TSA
) AS tradeshownamesA
GROUP BY CompanyID``